# XmlHttpRequest not reporting server side progress

Tags: xmlhttprequest, progress

I have a client server application. The server side is completely in java. The client side has a few lines of html and the rest in plain javascript (I don't use ajax or jquery etc).

The client receives user inputs through an input box and when the user clicks a button, the client sends a POST request to the server using XmlHtpRequest. The server then runs a process that can take several minutes.  The server periodically (every 5 seconds) sends a progress update message with HTTP status code 202 and with content "Processing.... completed 5 / 100". The numbers 5 and 100 are a sample. Instead of 100, it is the actual final counter of the process and instead of 5 it is the current counter indicating the progress. When the server finishes the processing it sends a 200 OK with the final output as the content. I have an output text area where I want to display the progress message during the processing and later the final output is also placed in the same output text area.

My client side javascript code is:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
function sendCommandToServer() {
    window.xhr.onreadystatechange = getServerResponse;
    window.xhr.open("POST", (document.domain + "/" + "executeCommand"), true);
    window.xhr.send("arguments and data for the command");
}
</script>

<script>
function getServerResponse() {
    if(window.xhr.status === 202) {
        myTextArea.value = window.xhr.responseText;
        window.xhr.onreadystatechange = getServerResponse;
        return;
    }
    if(window.xhr.status === 200) {
        myTextArea.value = window.xhr.responseText;
        return;
    }
    alert("processing error");
}
</script>
```

The server correctly gets the command and runs the process and finishes and produces the output. It also correctly sends the progress messages. But my client side javascript does not get all of them. I am able to get the 1st progress message from the server - something like - "Processing .... 5 / 100" - but after that I am not able to get further calls to getServerResponse() to continue updating the progress as and when the server sends messages. If I modify the server side to avoid sending progress and send only the final output result, it works correctly and I get the final output result displayed at the client. I run this on IE10 and Chrome, with the same behavior. Can xmlHttpRequest() be used for this use-case? Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this myself and trying to work out a method of achieving something similar.
I think the 202 status code is the only response you will get, ie the server will send a single response when it has accepted the job (202), or a 200 response when it has completed.

Source:
http://100pulse.com/http-statuscode/202.jsp

Comment: Morvael - I just now saw this response form you so I thought I will add what I finally did. After struggling (unsuccessfully) with trying to get the same xmlHttpRequest() for the command and the progress, I created 2 separate XmlHttpRequests(). The 1st one issues the command and waits for the final response while the 2nd one periodically polls the server for the progress.